# preg_replace THIS_IS_MY_VAR to thisIsMyVar

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Need to transform

```
PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE
```

to

```
propResourceType
```

or

```
setPropResourceType
```

Number of `_` and string length are not fixed.

I'm not really into `preg_replace`,
could you help me out

Comment: Have you tried ANYTHING yet?

Comment: You don't need preg_replace for this; you can do this with `explode`, `strtolower`, `ucfirst` and `implode`

Comment: I have used `explode` and `string` functions but I was looking for something smarter. I was afraid people asking _"why you don't use regex"_ - now the oposite is the case :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, an example of how a regular expression could help:

```
// match each underscore followed by a letter
echo preg_replace_callback('/_([a-z])/', function($m) {
    return strtoupper($m[1]); // upper case the letter
}, strtolower('PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE'));
```

Answer (score 8):

```
lcfirst(implode(array_map('ucfirst', explode('_', strtolower($str)))));
```

Comment: I can't decide if I should give you +1, because you've done it all on one line; or if I should give you -1, because you've done it all on one line.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution:

```
<?php
$step1 = strtolower("PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE"); // prop_resource_type
$step2 = str_replace("_"," ",$step1); // prop resource type
$step3 = ucwords($step2); // Prop Resource Type
$step4 = str_replace(" ","",$step3); // PropResourceType
$step5 = "set".$step4;
?>
```

Comment: PropResourceType doesnt look like either propResourceType nor setPropResourceType

Comment: @o0rebelious0o
`$step5 = "set".$step4;`

Comment: @Jesbus - you can edit your answer to include that.

Comment: @jesbus have a +1 for your effors ;)

Answer (score 1):

For additional completeness, an example of how a regular expression could help:

```
$subject = 'PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE';

// match uppercase varnames
echo preg_replace_callback('/[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)+/', function ($matches) {
    list($varName) = $matches;
    $varName = strtolower($varName);
    $varName = strtr($varName, '_', ' ');
    $varName = ucwords($varName);
    $varName = strtr($varName, [' ' => '']);

    $varName = 'set' . $varName;
    // or:
    // $varName[0] = strtolower($varName[0]);
    return $varName;
}, $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// php 5.3.0+
$initial = 'PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE';
$words   = explode('_', $initial);
foreach($words as &$word){
    $word = ucfirst(strtolower($word));
}
$final = implode($words);
echo $final;
// returns PropResourceType

// if you want a lowercase first letter just do
echo lcfirst($final);
// returns propResourceType
```

Comment: which part of your code does not run below PHP 5.3 ?

Comment: `lcfirst()` doesn't work below < PHP 5.3 and I'm not sure about passing by reference, but it doesn't seem to work http://3v4l.org/Z0cKg

Answer (score 0):

another solution

```
echo preg_replace("/_([a-z])/e", 'strtoupper("$1")', strtolower($str));
```

EDIT `e` modifier has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, so be carefull

EDIT2 @hakre was so angry, that I decided to mention, that the only problem is: `e` can cause `E_DEPRECATED` level error (usually, turned off on all production servers). Anyway it still works on all PHP versions

Comment: DO not suggest the e modifier. Take a callback instead, the performance is better and it's more compatible.

Comment: @hakre just open your eyes and read again, I wrote aboute it

Comment: Well, does it mean you just answer but you do not suggest what you write as an example in the answer? So if it's not a suggestion, why do you answer it then? And being careful with the `e` modifier means to not use it, and that is independent to the PHP version. *You* should prefer the callback as well in your answer.

Comment: "Deprecated" doesn't mean "don't use it or you will be cursed forever", it only means "try to use something else, if you want to". Sometimes they are not even better, just another syntax. But `e` still works in all PHP versions, so I still don't want to put 2 lines of function instead of `e` @hakre

Comment: The deprecation is not the reason why you should not suggest it. Understand why it has been deprecated. There is a reason behind. Take care.